# Unknown setting 'protocol' for elasticsearch 5.1.1

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

So I've been looking for the way to solve this issue all day long.
but all I've got is for the old version of elasticsearch.
fyi, i use the latest version of elk stack.

- elasticsearch version : <kbd>5.1.1</kbd>
- kibana version : <kbd>5.1.1</kbd>
- logstash version : <kbd>5.1.1</kbd>

This is my apache conf :

```
input {
    file {
        path => '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/access_log'
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
}

output {
     elasticsearch { protocol => "http" }
}
```

That file used to access log data from apache.

But when I run the logstash, with :

```
logstash -f apache.conf
```

I got this error message.

[image]

That message told me that something wrong with my configuration.
the http protocol is doesnt exist anymore i guess.

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Many thanks return

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `protocol` setting in the `elasticsearch` output anymore. Simply modify your output to this:

```
output {
    elasticsearch { 
       hosts => "localhost:9200" 
    }
}
```